# Merge all the lines when a specific string appears on that line

Tags: bash

When a certain string at the beginning of the line appears that I want them to merge together for example

I have something as follows in my text file multiple times, then I want to merge all the lines starts from ***payload_sizes (bytes)***

```
PerformanceINFO
            UVM_INFO_PERF ****NIB-FIB Axis Interface Per-packet Performance Report****
             interface_name            : NIB-FIB,
             payload_sizes (bytes)     : {1,2,3,4,5,6....10, }
             packet_datarate (bits/clk): {11,22,33,44,55,.....20, }


interface_name            : NIB-FIB,
                 payload_sizes (bytes)     : {100,202,303,405,5,6....10, }
                 packet_datarate (bits/clk): {11,22,33,44,55,.....20, }

interface_name            : NIB-FIB,
                 payload_sizes (bytes)     : {13,24,35,45,55,65....10, }
                 packet_datarate (bits/clk): {11,22,33,44,55,.....20, }
```

so what I am expecting is I want to merge all the lines that starts with "payload_sizes(bytes) merged in one line
and
"packet_datarate(bits/clk) merged together

```
Output should look like this
payload_sizes(bytes): 1,2,3,4,5,6....10,100,202,303,405,5,6....10,13,24,35,45,55,65....10
packet_datarate(bits/clk):11,22,33,44,55,.....20,11,22,33,44,55,.....20,11,22,33,44,55,.....20
```

Comment: Better provide an expected output example to help clarify your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F: '/packet_datarate/ { 
                             packt=packt""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) 
                           } 
         /payload_sizes/ { 
                             payl=payl""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) 
                           } 
                   END   { 
                             print "payload_sizes(bytes):,"payl;
                             print "packet_datarate(bits/clk):,"packt 
                          }' filename
```

One liner:

```
awk -F: '/packet_datarate/ { packt=packt""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) } /payload_sizes/ { payl=payl""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) } END { print "payload_sizes(bytes):,"payl;print "packet_datarate(bits/clk):,"packt }' filename
```

Process each line of the file and search for "packet_datarate". If it exists, take the second : separated field and strip all spaces, { and }. Add the remaining text (str) to a variable packt. Do the same for "payload_sizes" adding data to a variable payl. At the end, print both variable formatted in the correct manner.

Comment: And to put the output in the excel sheet then we have to say as following?



awk -F: '/packet_datarate/ { packt=packt""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) } /payload_sizes/ { payl=payl""gensub(/[ {}]/,"","g",$2) } END { print "payload_sizes(bytes):"payl;print "packet_datarate(bits/clk):"packt }' result_after_Extraction_nov_Build749_NIB.txt>> result_get_after_merge_extracted_info_for_graph.csv

Comment: I've added a comma to the end of: on the prints. This should allow you to output to a csv file.

Comment: I am able to get the desired output in the output.txt but when I am trying to copy it and trying to paste it in speed sheet then it's not able to paste it, is there a way I could do that ?

Comment: Just the open the file as a csv?

Comment: my output file extension is Output_file.xlsx and when I am trying to open it in Excell sheet on windows then it's giving the following error message.

Error Mesage: Excel cannot open the file 'file_name.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: You need to open Excel first and then open file, select type csv

Comment: There is no CSV in the type list 

all I see is in the drop-down
All Files
All Excel Files
Excel Files
XML Files
All Web Pages

Comment: OK, select all files, select the csv file and click OK

Comment: Thank you you are best. However, since the data is so big it said "could not load completely"  thank you again.

Comment: Mr. Raman 

What if I don't want to merge them and get printed every time they appear is it possible? 

at the list that I won't be over loading the excel sheet because of which my data is getting lost

Comment: Can we do the above code in python that way we can plot the graphs automatically, what's your opinion, please?